# error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object while pushing code using Git & GPG keychain

Tags: mobile-automation, git, mac, gitlab

Trying to push/commit my code using Git. Facing:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Background :

- Everything was working absolutely expected way till today
- Accidentally observing error on Git
- System : MAC
- Application Git & GPG keychain

If anyone observed this before and have working solution please share.

Comment: @Community, How experts can say this question is not related to testing? We are not agreed that Automation testing is a part of testing? 
Unknowingly closing the question is the ultimate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution work for me is :

- Firstly I tried to get details about why this is NOT working. Try below cmd on terminal

```
   $ echo "Hello" > test.txt
   $ gpg --sign --default-key <your-email-id> test.txt
```

- Observed error with details : **gpg: signing failed: No pinentry**

> ```
> gpg-agent[59045]: can't connect to the PIN entry module '/usr/local/bin/pinentry': IPC connect call failed
> gpg-agent[59045]: failed to unprotect the secret key: No pinentry
> ```

- From terminal I hit below cmd :

```
    cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

- Check if below statement is present. **Need to add if not present in gpg-agent.conf**

> pinentry-program
> /usr/local/MacGPG2/libexec/pinentry-mac.app/Contents/MacOS/pinentry-mac

- After adding pinentry path, Run

```
    $ gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
    $ gpg --sign --default-key <your-email-id> test.txt
```

- See the output :

```
 gpg: using <your-email-id> as default secret key for signing
```